# How to merge filled row until find the blank cell repeatedly

Tags: excel, vba

I want to merge multiple filled row until found the blank row/cell. I guess you have to see the picture in order to understand my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another technique that should be faster than looping throug all rows.

First of all this starst at the end of the sheet and loops backwards.
This technique uses the `.End(xlUp)` method to jump over the empty rows to the next data and then uses `.CurrentRegion` to find all data until the next empty cell to then join it.

Because it jumps over the empty areas it should be faster that looping through all of the cells.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub MergeConinousCells()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim RangeToJoin As Range
    Set RangeToJoin = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A") 'initialize with very last cell

    Do Until RangeToJoin.Row <= 1 'loop until we reach the first row
        Set RangeToJoin = RangeToJoin.Offset(RowOffset:=-1).Resize(RowSize:=1).End(xlUp).CurrentRegion.Resize(ColumnSize:=1)
        If RangeToJoin.Rows.Count > 1 Then 'if more than one cell in this area then join them
            ws.Cells(RangeToJoin.Row, "C").Value = Join(WorksheetFunction.Transpose(RangeToJoin), ";")
        Else 'only one cell so transfer value only
            ws.Cells(RangeToJoin.Row, "C").Value = RangeToJoin.Value
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your image something like this should work...

```
Option Explicit
Sub merge()

Dim arr() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim a As Integer
Dim ColALastRow As Long
Dim FRow As Long

ColALastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
FRow = 0
a = 0

For i = 1 To ColALastRow

Do While ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) <> vbNullString
ReDim Preserve arr(0 To a) As Variant
FRow = FRow + 1
arr(a) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
i = i + 1
a = a + 1
Loop

If Len(Join(arr, "")) <> 0 Then
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i - FRow, 2) = Join(arr, ";")
FRow = 0
a = 0
Erase arr
End If

Next

End Sub
```